# unable to ping with hostname from same machine in linux

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, centos7

I setup 2 centos7 machines(A & B) with hostname and static ip address. logged into machine A. then tried to ping with hostname of machine A. it is pinging. Logged into machine B. then tried to ping with hostname of machine B. but it is not pinging. not sure whether any configuration missed.

Below is the output from A machine

```
[rmdev01@inches-rmdev01 ~]$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
<ip address> inches-rmdev01.aaitg.com

[rmdev01@inches-rmdev01 ~]$ cat /etc/hostname
inches-rmdev01

[rmdev01@inches-rmdev01 ~]$ ping inches-rmdev01
PING inches-rmdev01 (<ip address>) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from inches-rmdev01.aaitg.com (<ip address>): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.034 ms
64 bytes from inches-rmdev01.aaitg.com (<ip address>): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.082 ms
64 bytes from inches-rmdev01.aaitg.com (<ip address>): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.050 ms
64 bytes from inches-rmdev01.aaitg.com (<ip address>): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.050 ms
```

Below is the output from B machine.

```
[rmtest01@inches-rmtest01 ~]$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
<ip address> inches-rmtest01.aaitg.com

[rmtest01@inches-rmtest01 ~]$ cat /etc/hostname
inches-rmtest01

[rmtest01@inches-rmtest01 ~]$ ping inches-rmtest01
ping: unknown host inches-rmtest01
```

From A machine

```
[rmdev01@inches-rmdev01 ~]$ hostname
inches-rmdev01
[rmdev01@inches-rmdev01 ~]$ hostname -f
inches-rmdev01
```

From B machine

```
[rmtest01@inches-rmtest01 ~]$ hostname
inches-rmtest01
[rmtest01@inches-rmtest01 ~]$ hostname -f
inches-rmtest01.aaitg.com
```

Comment: Compare the contents on `/etc/resolv.conf` on both servers. My guess is that `search` differs

Comment: @dwjv: i checked. contents are same in both the machines.

Comment: Does it work when you `ping inches-rmtest01.aaitg.com`? Or the actual IP address?

Comment: @dwjv. yes. it is working if i try with domain name. but we dont want to ping with domain name. that is the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify `/etc/hosts` and add to the last line short hostname like that:

```
...
<ip address> inches-rmtest01.aaitg.com inches-rmtest01
```

Or you have to specify search domain to `aaitg.com` by modifying `/etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: adding hostname without domain did the trick. but i wonder how it worked in A machine without adding this.

Comment: @divakar.scm you have to show content of `/etc/resolv.conf` of both machines.

Comment: @divakar.scm I'm pretty sure that the machine **A** has the following line `search aaitg.com` in file `/etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: in both the machines it has "search aaitg.com". please check my reply to dwjv.

Comment: @divakar.scm you are right. Can you do `ping inches-rmdev01` on machine **B**? What is the result?

Comment: no it wont. only i am able to ping with ip address.

Comment: @divakar.scm perhaps you have set domain name in file `/etc/sysconfig/network` for the machine **A** but not for the machine **B**?

Comment: thanks for your patience and helping me. no. network file doesnt have domain name entry.

Comment: @divakar.scm can you execute `hostname` and `hostname -f` on the both machines?

Comment: Edited my question with the details you asked.

Comment: @divakar.scm you have to find where the domain name is set in you machine **B**. Try to use this: `cd /etc ; sudo grep -r 'aaitg\.com'`